# Using a bit input in stored procedure to determine how to filter results in the where clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm beating my head against the wall here... can't figure out a way to pull this off.

Here's my setup:

My table has a column for the date something was completed.  If it was never completed, the field is null.  Simple enough.

On the front end, I have a checkbox that defaults to "Only show incomplete entries".  When only pulling incomplete entries, it's easy.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM Sometable
WHERE Completed_Date IS NULL
```

But offering the checkbox option complicates things a great deal.  My checkbox inputs a bit value: 1=only show incomplete, 0=show all.

The problem is, I can't use a CASE statement within the where clause, because an actual value uses "=" to compare, and checking null uses "IS".  For example:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM Sometable
WHERE Completed_Date IS   <---- invalid syntax
    CASE WHEN
        ...
    END


SELECT
    *
FROM Sometable
WHERE Completed_Date =
    CASE WHEN @OnlyIncomplete = 1 THEN
        NULL     <----- this translates to "WHERE Completed_Date = NULL", which won't work.. I have to use "IS NULL"
        ...
    END
```

Any idea how to accomplish this seemly easy task? I'm stumped... thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
...
WHERE @OnlyIncomplete = 0
    OR (@OnlyIncomplete = 1 AND Completed_Date IS NULL)
```

Comment: Simple and elegant solution.  Much easier than I expected.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... I think what you want is this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM Sometable
WHERE Completed_Date IS NULL OR (@OnlyIncomplete = 0)
```

So that'll show Date=NULL plus, if OnlyIncomplete=0, Date != Null. Yeah, I think that's it.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use a CASE function (although it may be overkill in this case) :

```
SELECT
    *
FROM Sometable
WHERE 1 = 
    (CASE WHEN @OnlyIncomplete = 0 THEN 1
          WHEN @OnlyIncomplete = 1 AND Completed_Date IS NULL THEN 1
     END)
```